# Как затемнить фото на сайте?

Tags: html, css

Я хочу, что-бы фото были, как-бы черно-белим,  а когда наводишь на них, они становились нормальными.
Как это осуществить?
только не  opacity у фото и background: black, так оно будет темным, но цвета будут видны

Короче мне надо сделать фото черно-белым

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю изображение не чёрно-белое, а в градациях серого?
Тогда вам нужен фильтр **`Gray()`**

```
<DIV ID="GrayId" STYLE="width:320; height:240;
    filter:Gray()">
<IMG src="image.jpg" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240"></DIV>
```

P.S. Ну, и, разумеется, использовать события **DHTML** (*onMouseOver* и *onMouseOut*).

Comment: ННо работать будет только в старом-добром IE в других браузерах это нереально :)

Comment: Лучше не пытаться пользоваться некроссбраузерными методами.

Comment: Можете предложить другой (кроссбраузерный) способ замены цвета, а не **затемнения**?

Answer (score 3):

Можно просто поверх фото динамически строить черный объект "div" с прозрачностью 0.4 - 0.6.
И затем обрабатывать у него событие "onmouseover()" на удаление объекта.

Comment: Ну уж тогда не строить, а показывать/прятать.

Comment: Ну это уже как вам угодно =)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по тегам, вам надо только средствами html+css. Тогда самый простой способ:

**HTML**

```
<div class="grey_color"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grey_color {
    width: 100px; /* размеры свои */
    height: 100px;
    background: url(путь_к_чернобелой_картинке/grey.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.grey_color:hover {
    background: url(путь_к_цветной_картинке/color.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: да нет, без двойных картинок, вроде бы через SVG можно?

Comment: @ZoZexZero, для SVG и картинки должны быть SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка HTML 5 canvas такое можно реализовать, ну а вообще я бы на серваке делал вторую копию в чб цветах ...